# how do you mention

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to mention a specific role with the id `631147065925173310`. I have tried everything and a lot of people said to me that I don't know python, which is hard, but I am learning how to use `discord.py` for only 2 days.

```
if channel.name == "General":
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}needs help at{channel.mention})
else:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author}needs help at an unknown place")
```

I want that whenever a person write 'h!' or help, it will say:

```
@user needs help at #channel @specific role
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
user = self.bot.get_user(ctx.author.id)
role = ctx.guild.get_role(631147065925173310)
await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} needs help in {ctx.channel.mention}, please attend {role.mention}")
```

If you are using this in a cog use my code and if you are using `bot` for commands.

If you are using this in the main command use `bot.get_user(ctx.author.id)` instead of what I have.

Answer (score 1):

To mention a role or user you should use this syntax in your message:

<@id>

So change "id" for the id of the respective role, so your code would be:

```
awit ctx.send(f"<@{userId}>nedds help at<@{channelId}>)
```